# Angular routing, create route using outlets

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I have my application which works without routing.
But there is a place where I can open Dialog window, which also doesn't need routing.

In this dialog I have a button. If I click on this button, slide panel shoud appear, which I also can close.

I use route-outlet to open slide panel.

In Html I have something like this:

```
<button (click)="showAddLinkSlidePanel()"></button>
<router-outlet name="addLinkSlidePanel"></router-outlet>
```

Typescript:

```
showAddLinkSlidePanel() {
        this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { addLinkSlidePanel: 'insert-link' } }], { state: 'some data here', skipLocationChange: true });
    }
```

So, I just redirect to another page without changing URL

When I import RouterModule from DialogWindow Module, I have this

```
RouterModule.forChild([
    {
        path: 'insert-link',
        component: AddLinkSlidePanelComponent,
        outlet: 'addLinkSlidePanel',
    },
])
```

and in my App.module

```
RouterModule.forRoot([])
```

But. If I open dialog window, click button to show slide panel, close it using route

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { addLinkSlidePanel: null } }], {
            skipLocationChange: false,
        });
```

I face with exception when after closing dialog and opening it again, slide panel is being shown..
I'm sure it's because I haven't imported RouteModule incorrectly. Maybe you can just give me advice what I do wrong. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've added

```
.forChild([
  {
    path: '',
    outlet: 'addLinkSlidePanel',
    component: null,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    path: 'insert-link',
    component: AddLinkSlidePanelComponent,
    outlet: 'addLinkSlidePanel',
    children: [],
  },
])
```

and

```
.forRoot([])
```

it works!